# forecasting resource utilization

Tags: algorithm, r, time-series

I want to create a system to forecast certain resource utilization; for example, CPU utilization. I have data of CPU utilization for each day. How can I predict its usage for next future time, say 2 days? I know that time series analysis can help but I fail to understand how to accommodate other factors associated with the CPU utilization as time series analysis is only time on x-axis and utilization on y-axis.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil!

Comment: I would start [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) and see what you can learn.  Your question is very broad and open ended.  It sounds like you should  research some on your own and come up with a few specific questions related to your problem rather than a single broad questions about time-series.

Comment: This isn't a programming question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, i think it can help you a lot or at least help you start with something. He deals with a similar problem (forecasting of hard disk space requirements)

http://lpenz.github.com/articles/df0pred-1/index.html

http://lpenz.github.com/articles/df0pred-2/index.html

http://lpenz.github.com/articles/df0pred-3/index.html

Comment: If it works for you, please share your thoughts and methods. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I deduce that you have multiple time series, and that you want to put this extra information at work (as opposed to a univariate model solely with cpu utilization).

For a univariate model, you can check with `arima()`, and find a suitable order for this model using `auto.arima()` in package `forecast`. Predictions can be made using `predict()`, on the arima object.

For a multivariate model, you can consider a vector auto-regressive model. Check for function `VAR()` in package `vars`.